# Python syntax error using fig=plt

Tags: python, syntax, syntax-error

I know syntax errors are probably annoying to answer but I'm new and working through some tutorials and running in some issues.  Here is first:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import numpy as np

def graphRawFX():
    date,bid,ask = np.loadtxt('GBPUSD1d.txt', unpack=True,
                              delimiter=',',
                              converters={0:mdates.strpdate2num('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')}
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,7))
    ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((40,40), (0,0), rowspan=40, colspan=40)

    ax1.plot(date,bid)
    ax1.plot(date,ask)

    ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))

    plt.grid(True)
    plt.show()
```

This throws:

```
  File "C:\Users\Name\Desktop\one_day_ohlc\AlgoTradingTutorial.py", line 18
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,7))
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Hopefully it isn't lack of sleep and I'm just missing something obvious, thank you everyone.

Comment: When in doubt, look at the *preceding* line; you are missing a closing `)` there and Python continues parsing the next line as part of that statement.

Comment: Any decent editor/IDE should help highlight this type of error. try pycharm community edition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
date,bid,ask = np.loadtxt('GBPUSD1d.txt', unpack=True,
                          delimiter=',',
                          converters={0:mdates.strpdate2num('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')}
```

Looks like you're missing a parentheses here.

```
date,bid,ask = np.loadtxt('GBPUSD1d.txt', unpack=True,
                          delimiter=',',
                          converters={0:mdates.strpdate2num('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')})
```

Comment: TY so much, thanks for patience w/ a noob!  I have one more error will post in another question.